# How to construct a for loop if I need a different ending in different cases?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a task to construct a data frame with a given rules:

There is a vector like `V<-c(10, 20, 15, 22, 60)`. I need length (V) columns and `max(V)` rows. For each i-column I need V[i] values. For example for first column I need 10 non-zero values and 50 zeros, for the second col I need 20 non zero values and 40 zeros. For this issue I run a code:

```
EL<-matrix( rep( 0, len=3400), nrow = 8)
for (i in 1:8){
  for (j in 1:(n[i])){
    EL[j,i]<-100*p[i]*LGD[i]
  }
}
```

It shows an error

> Error in [<-(*tmp*, j, i, value = 100 * p[i] * LGD[i]) :
>   subscript out of bounds`. Should I do an ifelse loop or there is any possible ways to solve this problem&

Comment: Hello @Galina Pazhitnova, please can you further explain the zero values? I get that you need the number of values in each column in V, but how do you calulate de number of zeros, that is I get the 10 non-zero values, but why 50 zeros?

Answer (score 5):

I would create a sparse matrix:

```
library(Matrix)

V<-c(10, 20, 15, 22, 60)

M <- sparseMatrix(dims = c(max(V), length(V)), 
                  i = sequence(V), j = rep(seq_along(V), V))
#60 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "ngCMatrix"
#               
# [1,] | | | | |
# [2,] | | | | |
# [3,] | | | | |
# [4,] | | | | |
# [5,] | | | | |
# [6,] | | | | |
# [7,] | | | | |
# [8,] | | | | |
# [9,] | | | | |
#[10,] | | | | |
#[11,] . | | | |
#[12,] . | | | |
#[13,] . | | | |
#[14,] . | | | |
#[15,] . | | | |
#[16,] . | . | |
#[17,] . | . | |
#[18,] . | . | |
#...
```

If for some reason you really need a dense integer matrix (why would you?), you could then do `+as.matrix(M)`.

Answer (score 3):

Another option for the function inside `sapply` is to take advantage of the fact that `rep` accepts a vector for the `times` argument. This repeats `1` `x` times, and then repeats `0` `V_max - x` times.

```
V <- c(10, 20, 15, 22, 60)
V_max <- max(V)
mat <- sapply(V, function(x) rep(c(1L, 0L), times = c(x, V_max - x)))

mat

#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#  [1,]    1    1    1    1    1
#  [2,]    1    1    1    1    1
#  [3,]    1    1    1    1    1
#  [4,]    1    1    1    1    1
#  [5,]    1    1    1    1    1
#  [6,]    1    1    1    1    1
#  [7,]    1    1    1    1    1
#  [8,]    1    1    1    1    1
#  [9,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [10,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [11,]    0    1    1    1    1
# [12,]    0    1    1    1    1
# [13,]    0    1    1    1    1
# [14,]    0    1    1    1    1
# [15,]    0    1    1    1    1
# [16,]    0    1    0    1    1
# [17,]    0    1    0    1    1
# [18,]    0    1    0    1    1
# [19,]    0    1    0    1    1
# [20,]    0    1    0    1    1
# [21,]    0    0    0    1    1
# [22,]    0    0    0    1    1
# ...
```

Now for a sillier solution (same result except has column names)

```
m <- matrix(0, max(V), length(V))
+(data.frame(row(m)) <= as.list(V))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `sapply` and `tabulate`

```
V <- c(10, 20, 15, 22, 60)
V_max <- max(V)
sapply(V, function(x) {
  tabulate(seq_len(x), nbins = V_max)
})
```

Result

```
head(mat, 25)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [3,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [4,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [5,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [6,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [7,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [8,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [9,]    1    1    1    1    1
#[10,]    1    1    1    1    1
#[11,]    0    1    1    1    1
#[12,]    0    1    1    1    1
#[13,]    0    1    1    1    1
#[14,]    0    1    1    1    1
#[15,]    0    1    1    1    1
#[16,]    0    1    0    1    1
#[17,]    0    1    0    1    1
#[18,]    0    1    0    1    1
#[19,]    0    1    0    1    1
#[20,]    0    1    0    1    1
#[21,]    0    0    0    1    1
#[22,]    0    0    0    1    1
#[23,]    0    0    0    0    1
#[24,]    0    0    0    0    1
#[25,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `vapply`

```
vapply(seq_along(V), function(k) c(rep(1L, V[k]),rep(0L, max(V) - V[k])), integer(max(V)))
# yielding
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [3,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [4,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [5,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [6,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [7,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [8,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [9,]    1    1    1    1    1
[10,]    1    1    1    1    1
[11,]    0    1    1    1    1
[12,]    0    1    1    1    1
[13,]    0    1    1    1    1
[14,]    0    1    1    1    1
[15,]    0    1    1    1    1
[16,]    0    1    0    1    1
[17,]    0    1    0    1    1
[18,]    0    1    0    1    1
[19,]    0    1    0    1    1
[20,]    0    1    0    1    1
[21,]    0    0    0    1    1
...
```